# WP8 how to open selected item directly into edit view

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

WP8, VS2012

I'm looking to take an item from the main page...

[image]

and reopen it directly into the page (or similar) where the content is immediately editable (maybe this is the same page where the content was originally created?)...

[image]

At present, I'm opening the selected item into a fresh details page using...

```
    private void OpenWinePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Capture selected item data
        _selectedItem = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;

        if (_selectedItem != null)
        {
            // Send ID of selected contact
            string dest = "/WinePage.xaml?toDoItemId=" + ((ToDoItem)_selectedItem).ToDoItemId;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(dest, UriKind.Relative));
```

If I change the 'string dest = "/NewPage.xaml...", I open the page to create a new item.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Is there a sample available?

Many Thanks,

R

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `Grid`/`StackPanel` with the editable fields in your page below your `ListBox` and set it's `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

Once an item gets selected, you can populate the fields; set the `Visibility` of the `ListBox` to `Collapsed` then set the `Visibility` of the  `Grid` that is holding the editable fields to `Visibile`.